# ¿Por qué js marca este error,? Trato de guardar en bd desde un form-modal. Pero al dar guardar marca error en un archivo, js

Tags: javascript, php

```
    $( "#guardarDatos" ).submit(function( event ) {
    var parametros = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../Controller/agregar_alum.php",
                data: parametros,
                 beforeSend: function(objeto){
                    $("#datos_ajax_register").html("Almacenando...");
                  },
                success: function(datos){
                $("#datos_ajax_register").html(datos);

                load(1);
              }
        });
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

> Error al inspeccionar: POST
>   jquery.min.js:4 
>        http://localhost:8080/cebProcedular/View/Controller/agregar_alum.php
>   404 (Not Found)

Comment: ya verificaste si la ruta de la url es la correcta?

Comment: El servidor no está respondiendo a peticiones hechas a:
http://localhost:8080/cebProcedular/View/Controller/agregar_alum.php

Comment: como esta  en la linea se cambia, porque el archivo php, no esta en View, esta directo en Controlller,

Comment: Osea que la url sería cebProcedular/Controller/agregar_alum.php, ademas el `event.preventDefault();` debe ir antes de la variable `parametros`

Comment: asi, es como esta en el archvo js: "../Controller/agregar_alum.php",

Comment: cual es la ruta del archivo javascript?, al parecer es un error de la ruta

Comment: cebProcedural/js/app.js

Comment: Me estoy imaginando que el directorio `Controller` no está dentro del directorio `View` y que te falta un `../` a la url (siendo `url: "../../Controller/agregar_alum.php"`). Podrías probar a usar una ruta absoluta para la url (algo del tipo `/cebProcedular/Controller/agregar_alum.php`) y así evitarías posibles problemas si se llama desde diferentes niveles

Comment: si, creo que eso era. muchas gracias saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás haciendo la petición ajax a una url relativa.

Empieza por usar una url absoluta del tipo

```
/Controller/...
```

En vez de

```
../Controller/...
```

Y luego ve si es viable mantener esa url absoluta en producción. Puede que quieras deployar a un subdirectorio y eso entra en conflicto con lo anterior.